# Datapump metadata-only import changes datalength when importing with conversion

Tags: oracle, unicode, data-conversion

Datapump metadata only import changes datalength when importing with conversion: (export done in WE8ISO8859P15 and import done in AL32UTF8 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set)

Example table:
Source-SYSTEM (WE8ISO8859P15):

```
select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_LENGTH from dba_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME='STRING';

OWNER TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_LENGTH
--------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
SCHEMA_NAME STRING DE 2000
```

Target-SYSTEM (AL16UTF16):

```
select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_LENGTH from dba_tab_columns where TABLE_NAME='STRING';

OWNER TABLE_NAME COLUMN_NAME DATA_LENGTH
--------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
SCHEMA_NAME STRING DE 4000
```

The data length of varchar2(char 2000) has been changed to varchar2(char 4000) automatically. What is the rule set for this behavior? Is this a documented behavior?

Edit: The issue seem to be not related to datapump but to the conversion from single character to multicharacter set:

Source-SYSTEM (WE8ISO8859P15):

```
create table test(name varchar2(50), name2 varchar2(5 char), name3 clob);

INSERT INTO test VALUES('Susanne','Test','Hi This is Row one');

select owner,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, CHAR_LENGTH, data_type,char_used FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='TEST';
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME    50  50  VARCHAR2    B
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME2   5   5   VARCHAR2    C
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME3   4000    0   CLOB
```

Target-SYSTEM (AL16UTF16):

```
create table test(name varchar2(50), name2 varchar2(5 char), name3 clob);

INSERT INTO test VALUES('Susanne','Test','Hi This is Row one');

select owner,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, CHAR_LENGTH, data_type,char_used FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='TEST';
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME    50  50  VARCHAR2    B
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME2   20  5   VARCHAR2    C
SCHEMA_NAME TEST    NAME3   4000    0   CLOB
```

Note: In old DB (character set = WE8ISO8859P15)
DATA_LENGTH=1*CHAR_LENGTH for all columns having VARCHAR2 DATA_TYPE (indipendent of CHAR_USED).

In new DB (with UNICODE character set AL32UTF8)
DATA_LENGTH=4*CHAR_LENGTH (or max-value = 4000) for all columns having VARCHAR2 DATA_TYPE and CHAR_USED=C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we create `VARCHAR2(5)` or `VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)`, we put constraint on max 5 bytes.

If we create `VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)`, we put constraint on max 5 characters.

In `WE8ISO8859P15` every character consists of 1 byte, so `VARCHAR2(5)` is equivalent to `VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)` and `DATA_LENGTH` = `CHAR_LENGTH`.

In `AL16UTF16` every character consists of 2 bytes and in all cases `DATA_LENGTH` =
`2 * CHAR_LENGTH`.

In `AL32UTF8` character may consist of 1-4 bytes. So `VARCHAR2(5)` and `VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)` will put constraint on max 5 bytes (five 1-byte characters will fit, two 4-byte characters will not fit). And `VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)` will put constraint on max 5 characters, so in worst scenario five 4-byte characters will fit and `DATA_LENGTH` will be `4 * CHAR_LENGTH`.

Comment: We also have opened an SR at oracle support. Oracle support: “It is an expected behavior as WE8ISO8859P15 is single Byte Characterset where as AL32UTF8 is Multibyte Characterset hence moving data from Single Byte characterset to Multibyte characterset will increase the length of the data ..”